# How to get large decimal numbers in np.arange in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

The below code works if value is 0.1 or 0.2..it is not working if value is 0.3475777755

```
def sentiment_score(value):
  if value in np.arange(-5,-2,0.1,dtype=float):
   return 'do_verynegative'
 elif value in np.arange(-2,0,0.1,dtype=float):
   return 'do_negative'
 elif value in np.arange(0,1,0.1,dtype=float):
   return 'do_neu'
 elif value in np.arange(0,2,0.1,dtype=float):
   return 'do_postive'
 elif value in np.arange(2,5,0.1,dtype=float):
   return 'do_verypositive'
  else:
    return 'error'
```

Please say how to do if the value has more than 1 decimal numbers?

Comment: Why don't you use `if (-5 <= value && value < -2)`?

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/160939) right here. Please show us more of your code as there's almost certainly a much better way to do all of this. You could use `np.allclose` to get around testing float equality, but I suspect the first fix is to use the method suggested by the previous comment. The next step will probably be to use a dictionary to dispatch the functions in a neater way. The best way may be to write a single NumPy function takes care of this in one step...

Comment: its showing invalid syntax/.

Comment: In actual Python syntax, that would be `if -5 <= value < -2:`.

Comment: Sorry am new to python,again in this elif -2 <= value < 0: its showing IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: @user3198036 That's a different problem. In your function the indentation is *not* consistent. The first `if` is indented more than the `elif`s.

Answer (score 1):

You want to translate a single number to a label, right? This code would achieve that for floats and integers.

```
def sentiment_score(value):
    if value <= -2:
        return 'do_verynegative'
    elif value <= 0:
        return 'do_negative'
    elif value <= 1:
        return 'do_neutral'
    elif value <= 2:
        return 'do_positive'
    else:
        return 'do_verypositive'
```